# XPath to join selected strings or text nodes with separators?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <alpha><name>John</name></alpha>
  <alpha><name>Peter</name></alpha>
  <beta>
    <alpha><name>Fred</name></alpha>
  </beta>
  <alpha><name>James</name></alpha>
</root>
```

My requirement is the following output:

```
John Peter James
```

I tried using the following XPath:

```
//following-sibling::alpha/name
```

But the output I get is:

```
John Peter Fred James
```

Can someone point me to the correct XPath I need to use to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XPath `/root/alpha/name`. It only selects

```
JohnPeterJames
```

How to format the output does depend on your environment. For example, in XSLT, you have to mask out the default templates which copy all `text()` nodes - including `Fred`. You could do this masking with `<xsl:template match="text()" />` clearing all *not-selected* text nodes.

The way of adding possible spaces between the names also depends on your XPath processor.

Answer (score 0):

### XPath 1.0

Only doable directly in XPath 1.0 with a known, fixed number of text nodes...

This XPath,

```
concat((/root/alpha/name)[1], ' ',
       (/root/alpha/name)[2], ' ',
       (/root/alpha/name)[3], ' ')
```

will return

```
John Peter James
```

as requested.

If you have unknown number of text nodes to join, use the hosting language or XPath 2.0...

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
string-join(/root/alpha/name, ' ')
```

will return

```
John Peter James
```

as requested.